# What is the procedure for recapturing rescued men?

Tags: little-wars

In Little Wars, captured men can be rescued by killing one or more of their captors. What is the procedure for recapturing the men who were just rescued?

For example, 14 men of team A attack 12 isolated men of team B. This results in 4 men of team A with 2 prisoners from team B. Now, suppose team B kills 1 of the captors from team A with cannon fire. How (if at all) could team A recapture those 2 men from team B?

They couldn't melee because the men from team B are disarmed. Would team A just have to move their men within six inches of the ex-prisoners to automatically recapture them? Would the procedure be different if there were armed men from team B nearby?